# ¿Cómo dar visibilidad de mi contenedor MySQL a mi contenedor Node?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy intentando conectarme a la base de datos con mi otro contenedor y siempre me arroja `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`.

No entiendo donde está problema de visibilidad entre contenedores.

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app
ENV HOME=/home/app
COPY package.json $HOME/my_project/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*
USER app 
WORKDIR $HOME/my_project
RUN npm install --silent --progress=false
USER root
COPY . $HOME/my_project
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*
USER app
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
networks:
    my_network:
        driver: bridge
services:
    database:
        container_name: my_mysql
        image: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: www_test
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - '~/docker-volumes/test/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        restart: always
        networks:
            - my_network
    app:
        container_name: my_app
        build: .
        command: 'npm run serve'
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        depends_on:
            - database
        volumes:
            - '.:/home/app/my_project'
            - /home/app/my_project/node_modules
        restart: always
        networks:
            - my_network
```

Comment: Que host o ip estas usando para conectarte a la base del otro contenedor?

Comment: @LeonardoCabré 127.0.0.1

Comment: si ejecutas esto puedes pinguear entre containers? `docker exec -ti app ping database`

Comment: Mi prueba en el comentario anterior es para verificar que efectivamente haya comunicaciones entre los containers, el 'host' que debieras usar en el container de la app para conectarte a la base debería ser `database` que es nombre del servicio que le diste al container de la base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya he dado con la solución, no indicar el driver y exponer los puertos de ambos servicios.

> .env

```
NODE_ENV=development

APP_PORT=3000
DB_PORT=3306

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --pure-lockfile
COPY . .
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: 'npm run serve'
    env_file:
        - .env
    ports: 
        - '${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}'
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/app/
        - /usr/app/node_modules
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes: 
        - ~/DockerVolumes/my_project/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
        - .env
    command: 'mysqld'
    ports: 
        - '${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}'
```

#### Comandos

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones bro! Sigue así, eleva ese cosmos y dale con todo el power 2.0!!! Saludos :D